# Setting a static IP for my router eventually prevents computer from being able to web

Tags: router, connection, static-ip, hosting

To start with, here's some **background on my problem**:

I recently started hosting my own site via gandi.net and have been hosting it on a personal server. I spoke to gandi.net about this and they believed the best way to do this was to set a static IP for my home address. So I set a static IP for my home router that connects both my personal desktop (an iMac) to the web and the server (using an acer notebook with Ubuntu server and an nginx server). I am using a netgear router and am forwarding ports 80 and 20-22 to the internal IP that is my server.

**Here's the problem:**

While I am able to set the static IP and everything works well initially, after around one week my iMac is no longer able to access the rest of the web. The only way I am able to get back to normal internet usage via either ethernet or wifi is to revert back to getting my IP dynamically from my ISP using the netgear genie. I can then access the rest of the web normally, but my website isn't up as gandi.net no longer points to the correct IP.

**I am quite new to all of this, so would appreciate if anyone had any thoughts on where I might be going wrong or where to start troubleshooting.** It has proven difficult for me to get to the root of the problem as it only appears days or weeks after I switch to a static IP and when it does happen my options are limited as I don't have web access.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: You might want to speak to your ISP about your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, your ISP will not assign a static IP address unless you pay for one.  You can't just change the IP address you get from your ISP to static from dynamic.
What's likely happening here is that your ISP releases and renews your IP address weekly, breaking your connection.  You have 2 options here:

1. If your ISP offers it, purchase a static IP from them
2. Use dynamic DNS (DDNS).  Dynamic DNS is a service you can get via the web and possibly your router.  DDNS will map your dynamic IP address to your domain name, and update the IP as it changes, so you don't need a static IP.

Netgear routers often have their own brand of DDNS built in, but there are others like Dyn DNS and ZoneEdit that may offer more features.